# PHP: Storing sensitive informations inside .ini file is good or bad approach?

Tags: php, security, ini

I'm confused about something and need some explanations.

In my practice I normaly see that 90% of PHP developers all sensitive informations like database connections, FTP, SMTP setup etc. store inside some variable, array, objects or constants.

I wonder now is better to use some ini file out of root and store there? Or is better to hide somewhere .ini file and deny access via .htaccess?

Generaly, I want to save that sensitive data on most secure way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no perfectly safe choice, but some are better than others.

Don't save sensitive information in your project's source code -- you don't want your passwords and API keys on github.

Saving sensitive information in a database is fine, but then you still need somewhere to store the database credentials, and you're right back where you started.

You can save sensitive information in environment variables. These would usually be set up in your web server's configuration file(s).

Saving sensitive information in an ini file is fine, provided the following:

- The file has the minimal permissions required.
- The file is completely outside the web server's document root and thus can't ever be served directly. Don't put the file in your main directory and then use .htaccess to deny access to it.
- The file is not committed to source control. If you're using git, edit your .gitignore so that the file is ignored.

These should also go without saying:

- The user account running the web server process should never have write permission to the files it's serving.
- Other non-privileged users on the machine running the web server process should not have read access to the files it's serving.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I would suggest to store it in a **dot file** such .env (like what Laravel does), or **environment variables**, or **INI file** (as what you said above) as long as it is hidden from the world or if some hack your server, they won't be able to see it easily or they won't be able to access it.

Comment: "they won't be able to see it easily" is absolutely _not_ the same as "they won't be able to see it". Definitions of "easily" can also vary according to how good a hacker you are.

Comment: Dot files aren't hidden from anything and provide exactly zero innate protection.

Comment: I agree with you +Alex that it is not hidden. I'm sorry for not elaborating but what I mean is - it should not be publicly available like if they user visits the url "https://example.com/.env", it shouldn't be displaying informations.

Comment: +ADyson - you're right about the "easily" definition. If you're a very good hacker this is super easy for you. I don't have really enough knowledge about hacking. I know some basic stuff like SQL injection, XSS, and etc... (but very basic hacking) but what I know is, if someone hacks your server, you should think about the damage would it costs. How easy for them to get those sensitive informations, the cost it gets if they every get those sensitive informations. Imagine, if you'll store it on a **config.php** file. That will be very super easy for them.

Comment: Anyway, as what I suggested above - "as long as  it is hidden (not super easy to locate), or if ever they access the server (hoping that they won't be able to access/view the file easily)". FYI, I agree with +Alex answer above, it's perfect, mine is like a additional or (very) brief version.